# I have just started coding and i have come to my first wall in python with an if statement

Tags: python-2.7

so my problem is that the print at the end wont work. can any one help me or tell me why it does this?

```
>>> name = "daug"
>>> if name == 'daug':
...  print "hello D"
... print "how are you"

file "<stdin>", line3
   print "how are you" //why do i get this?//
       ^
```

Comment: Can you post the error message? It works for me in Python 2.7. Are you sure you are using Python 2.7?

Comment: Is the second `print` supposed to be indented like the first? Otherwise it's out of the `if` block and should be entered on a new prompt `>>> ` not a continuation line `... `

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your error on my terminal:

```
>>> if name == "daug":
...  print "hello D"
... print "how are you"
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print "how are you"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

However, you didn't paste the last two lines (the SyntaxError exception, and the chevron)
You need to indent the the second print statement like you did the first. If the second print statement was not intended to be in the 'if' block, you have to hit < Enter> a second time after the first 'if' statement to let the interpreter know you are done with the 'if' block